# UIImage in a Rounded UIView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I created a UIView and inthe UIView, I added an Imageview. I gave the UIView corner radius and it works, the propble I have now is that the image that I place inside does not respect the cornerradius of the view and as a result, it shows the entire image as a rectangle instead of having the topleft and topRight corner curved to the same radius of the UIView. my code is shown below.

```
let bgView: UIView = {
        let bgView = UIView()
        bgView.backgroundColor = .white
        return bgView
    }()

    let propertyImage: DefaultImageView = {
        let img = DefaultImageView(frame: .zero)
        img.clipsToBounds = true
        img.layer.masksToBounds = true
        img.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icons8-name-filled-30")
        img.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return img
    }()
```

this gives the rounded cardview

```
extension UIView {
func addShadowAndRoundCorners() {
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = 12
    }
 }
```

so I added the rounded style like `bgView.addShadowAndRoundCorners`

How can I make the imageview stay withing the rounded corners of the UIView

Comment: Where do you set rounded corners? Why did you show this `bgView`? What is `DefaultImageView`?

Comment: @rmaddy, DefaultImage is just basics to avoid calling `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` every time. I set the rounded corners after adding the uiview as a subview  `bgView.addShadowAndRoundCorners()`

Comment: Please update your question with relevant code. We can't help you fix code that you don't show.

Comment: @rmaddy updated

Comment: You are showing random bits of code with no context. How are all of these pieces used and related? You need to post a reproducible example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clipsToBounds to yes needs to be added to the container view as well in order to force the subviews not to render outside:

```
bgView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Or you can just round the imageView itself.

Comment: this works but it removes the card property which is `layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor`

Comment: In that case, just add the same rounding to the imageView and it should work. clipsToBounds does interact with shadows unfortunately.

Comment: I only want the topleft and topRight corner curved

Comment: UIImageView is a subclass of a UIView, whatever you did to your view, you can do to your imageView as well.

Comment: I rounded the entire edge of the UIView

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the topLeft and topRight corners of the UIImageView rounded, you will probably have to use masking before displaying the image.

Create a CGContext the same size as the image, create the mask in the CGContext, then draw the image into the context, the mask will be applied, then get the new image from the context and put it in .image of the UIImageView.